# Unable to start Spring application ClassFormatError: Truncated class file

Tags: java, spring, java-8

What does this error mean exactly? I tried running this on other computer with older JDK versions and I don't get this issue. I also tried installing latest Eclipse version. Could it be a JDK bug? My JDK version is Java 8 1.8.0_171

```
2021-05-21 15:47:39 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.example.application.SomApolloIntegrationLauncher.main(SomApolloIntegrationLauncher.java:48)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionUtil.setAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:182)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.processable(ResourceInjector.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:120)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:116)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.loadAndRegister(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:227)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.activateAllByType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:142)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:145)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:157)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus.<init>(SpringBus.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:203)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Which class file is truncated? Maybe it's permission issues?

Answer (score 0):

It means that no byte code was found in the class file.  Can you open the class file in a decompiler?

Comment: I already put some breakpoints at bean instantiation it breaks correctly. I also decompiled my jar snapshots they seem to open.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project?  Sometimes working directories can become corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Check your cxf version.Maybe using previous cxf version solve problem